# Elastic sorting by most matches of filtered array

Tags: sorting, filter, elasticsearch

I have documents like:

```
{
  id : 1,
  title : One,
  tags : {
    {id : 1, title : One},
    {id : 2, title : Two},
    {id : 3, title : Three},
  }
},
{
  id : 2,
  title : Two,
  tags : {
    {id : 1, title : One},
    {id : 4, title : Four},
    {id : 5, title : Five},
  }
},
{
  id : 3,
  title : Three,
  tags : {
    {id : 1, title : One},
    {id : 2, title : Two},
    {id : 4, title : Four},
  }
}
```

I'm filtering by first item's `tags.id`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "ids": {
              "values": [1]
            }
          },
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "tags.id": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "tags.id": "2"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "tags.id": "3"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "track_scores": true,
  "size": 20,
  "sort": {
    "_score": "desc"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get result ordered by most matching tags? In this case item **Three** (2 matches) should be first and then item **Two** (1 match).
It seems if I use filter without a query, then the score is 1 for all items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "ids": {
                    "values": [1]
                }
            },
            "should": [
                {
                    "constant_score" : {
                        "filter" : {
                            "term": {
                                "tags.id": "1"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "constant_score" : {
                        "filter" : {
                            "term": {
                                "tags.id": "2"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "constant_score" : {
                        "filter" : {
                            "term": {
                                "tags.id": "3"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This query will ensure that the record with id = 1 is not on of the results and that the results are ordered such that the results with more matching tags come before the results with fewer matching tags.

Based on what you are looking for in the description you provided so far, I don't think the `filtered` query is necessary.  The `must_not` clause will filter out the undesired result.  The `bool` query with its defaults will handle the ordering you want.

Answer (score 0):

Probably @eemp's answer would work too, but I prefer to leave filter where possible, so it wouldn't be taken in to account on score count. So I moved tgas filter to query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "ids": {
              "values": [1]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "tags.id": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "tags.id": "2"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "tags.id": "3"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 20
}
```

Comment: That ids filter will not affect the score in the earlier answer.  I added the constant_score around the tag term queries so that the typical tf-idf scoring would not have an impact on the score.  So what you have will not always guarantee that results with more tag matches will appear before results with fewer tag matches (may be rare but depends on the data).  You can see this by passing "explain" : true in your query to see an explanation of the score - look out of term frequencies, inverse document frequencies, field norms in the explanation.

Comment: Ok :) So I checked your solution and it works. I don't entirely understand how, but I'll believe it's better ;) Thanks